# Rails Hash in javascript, access values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a following javascript code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="query_form_select_ops" id="query_form_select_ops" value='<%= schema%>'  />

<script>
  function select_pk2(cell){
  var val = $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_1').val();
  var opts = $('#query_form_select_ops').val();  
  }
</script>
```

Example:

`schema` is a typical ruby hash:

```
{ 
  "car"=>{"col"=>"blue", "engine"=>"HHd4M"},
  "train"=>{"col"=>"black", "engine"=>"8495f"}
}
```

The variable `val` has a value "train" and `opts` the whole ruby hash

To access the `col` and `engine` of a `train` in ruby: schema["train"]. How can I do the same in javascript?
I have tried:

```
var select = opts[val]
```

but it tells me that var in undefined. How can I access the values of a ruby hash in javascript given a hash and one of the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump `schema` hash as a json and then parse it back in javascript. Something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="query_form_select_ops" id="query_form_select_ops" value='<%= schema.to_json %>'  />
```

And script:

```
function select_pk2(cell){
  var val = $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_1').val();
  var opts = JSON.parse($('#query_form_select_ops').val());  
}
```

This way you should be able to access values in the way you want.

Each individual value of the hash in your example is hash as well, so you can access them by using proper keys. Like this:

```
opts['car']['col'];
```

Comment: I did it but if I alert(opts[val])  I get [object Object]. alert(opts[val][0]) and alert(opts[val][1]) are undefined

Comment: And that's normal behavior, as you also have hashes as nested values. And hash (in this case - javascript object) mapped on string is "[object Object]". You can access individual properties of each value as well. Try `console.log(opts[val])` and you should see the proper output on browser's dev console (on chrome or ff).

If you want `opts[val]` back as a string (json). Just do `JSON.stringify(opts[val])`, and you should get the json as the alert output.

Comment: I've updated the answer. No wonder you get `opts[val][0]` as undefined, as there's no such key in any of the hash values. Do `opts[val]['col']` for example.